# Python list comprehension with dicts and filters

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I have a list like this one:

```
l1 = [{'id':'78798798','gender':'Male'},
      {'id':'78722228','gender':'Female'},
      {'id':'33338','gender':'Male'}]
```

I need to check the length of a list obtained using a list comprehension and filtered by 'gender'.
I try

```
len([x for x in l1 if x['gender'] == "Male"])
```

but return an error
Then i try:

```
[[(k,v) for k,v in d.items()] for d in l1 if l1['gender'] == 'Male']
```

but return the same error and also

```
[[(k,v) for k,v in d.items() if k['gender'] == 'Male'] for d in l1]
```

How can i achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: print len([x for x in l1 if x['gender'] == "Male"]) should work

Comment: `In [2]: len([x for x in l1 if x['gender'] == "Male"])
Out[2]: 2` it works. maybe you pasted the wrong line?

Comment: key 'gender' id not found

Comment: Your second example has `l1` where it should have `d`: `[[(k,v) for k,v in d.items()] for d in l1 if d['gender'] == 'Male']`.

Comment: this means one of the dictionaries doesnt have a gender key

Comment: @Carcigenicate: What's wrong with dictionary wrapped in a list? It's more common than you think.

Comment: you can check if it has the key first: `len([x for x in l1 if 'gender' in x and x['gender'] == "Male"])`, but if every dictionary is supposed to have the `gender` key, it might mean that your data isn't structured the way you expected.

Comment: If you have a list with dictionaries, each with just two keys, a unique ID and some value, then it might be much simpler and generally more convenient to just have a single dict (or OrderedDict) like `{'78798798':'Male', '78722228':'Female', '33338':'Male'}`

Answer (score 2):

Clearly one of the dictionaries in the list doesn't have a `gender` key. You can get rid of this by adding an extra part to the list comprehension

```
len([x for x in l1 if "gender" in x and x['gender'] == "Male"])
```

Comment: Without repeating the key (prone to copy-paste errors): `if x.get('gender') == "Male"`, `get` returning `None` if the key is not present.

Comment: @tobias_k I'm sure I'm capable of spelling gender

Comment: Still, tobias_k suggestion looks more like python.

Comment: Never said that you would not, but what if you want to do this for all sorts of keys? Each time, you have to change two strings, and make sure that both are correct. And even if you _can_ spell a word, that does not mean that you (or anyone else) will never make a typo. But if you prefer long and repeating code, just keep it the way it is now.

Comment: @tobias_k if it were a really long piece of code with many repeats, of course I would change it, but for such a simple case, it's probably better to just have a slightly more readable version

Comment: Now I am curious: How is `if "gender" in x and x['gender'] == "Male"` more readable than `if and x.get('gender') == "Male"`? If you want to make explicit that `get` will return a default, you can use `x.get('gender', None)`. But anyway, it's your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably one of the entries is missing the gender field. Try

```
print([x for x in l1 if 'gender' not in x])
```

to find it.

Comment: you should probably use python3

Comment: or `[x for x in l1 if not x.get('gender')]`.  Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution:

`print(len([x for x in l1 if x['gender'] == "Male"]))`

It looks for elements in the list `l1` and checks if the value of equals to "Male".

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
l =[{'id':'78798798','gender':'Male'},
  {'id':'78722228','gender':'Female'},
  {'id':'33338','gender':'Male'}]
 len(filter(lambda x:  x['gender']=='Male', l))
```

Comment: How is swapping the list comp for filter supposed to fix whatever problem OP is having?

Answer (score 0):

You can try in one line like this :

```
print(len(list(filter(lambda x:x['gender']=='Male',l1))))
```

output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sum`:

```
l1 = [{'id':'78798798','gender':'Male'},
  {'id':'78722228','gender':'Female'},
  {'id':'33338','gender':'Male'}]
result = sum(i['gender'] == 'Male' for i in l1)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
2
```